# RecyclerView very slow in some device (not all)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Scrolling of RecyclerView is Very slow in some devices and normal in others 
i am facing this issue form 3 days and i tried many solutions form the internet and stackoverflow but all of them didn't fix this issue
i want to add xml layout many times  to inflated layout of ViewHolder
i make  for loop inside onBindViewHolder with xml layout to test scrolling 
but the scroll is very slow in some devices and work find with other divices 
here is my code of recycler view adapter

```
public class ExamQuestionsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExamQuestionsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public ExamQuestionsListAdapter(Context ctx, List<ExamQuestionsList> ex_Q_List) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.ex_Q_List = ex_Q_List;


    dbManger=new DataBaseManager(ctx);
    db=dbManger.getWritableDatabase();


    shared = ctx.getSharedPreferences("examsShared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.do_exam_card_view,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.c_m_layout,null);
        holder.questionsLayout.addView(v);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ex_Q_List.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    LinearLayout questionsLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        questionsLayout=(LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.q_layout);


    }
}
}
```

and this is xml file for layout inflated in method onCreateViewHolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/q_layout"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/question_tumber"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/question_title"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/res"
            />
    </LinearLayout>




</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is the xml file i use in for loop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:background="#FFF"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/c_m_q"
    />
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/first_choice"

        />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/second_choice"

            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/third_choice"

            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/fourth_choice"

            />

</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This line cost you -> View v=LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.c_m_layout,null);
        holder.questionsLayout.addView(v);

Comment: i have to add layouts inside holder because every holder has sub items should be in separated layout

Comment: No need to inflate layout 30 times just create one more ViewHolder class and assign data to that.

Comment: i did loop just for testing could you please wait for minutes i will try your solution

Comment: Your using recyclerview incorrectly. The cost of a view is very taxing I would suggest you make a hashmap to link sub items to their equals.

Comment: sorry i got lost could you please give me an example or any online tutorial

Answer (score 0):

NestedScrollView, as the name suggests, is used when there is a need for a scrolling view inside another scrolling view. Normally this would be difficult to accomplish since the system would be unable to decide which view to scroll.

This is where NestedScrollView comes in.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/keyline_1">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5" />

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/conversation"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

here you use nested with scroll behavior like adding below line in recycle view
**app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"**